# Getting ReferenceError: define is not defined when using jasmine syntax in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jestjs

**What am I doing wrong?** This feels like I'm missing something completely and totally obvious and simple.

Here is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "jest-test",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^21.2.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
// math.js
let add = (x, y) => x + y;
module.exports = {
    add
};
```

Here are my tests:

```
// math.test.js
const math = require('./math');

define('A math library', () => {
  it('can add two numbers', () => {
    expect(math.add(2,2)).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

Here is the result of running `npm test` from the command line:

[image]

FWIW, this code works as expected, but I prefer the jasmine syntax:

```
const math = require('./math');

test('can add two numbers', () => {
  expect(math.add(2,2)).toBe(4);
});
```

Comment: Looks like a typo to me - `define` should be `describe`.

Comment:  doh! Thanks. I knew it was something simple and obvious like that.

Comment: I also like the idea that the error could be `defined is not defined`....[but it is](http://media0.giphy.com/media/w3J7mstYCISqs/giphy.gif)